# show content of particular tab as its children

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a list of tabs which can be a category. The content for that specific tab or category should be shown just near and a bit bottom on its respective tab so that it gives a look of parent and children.

Here is how i have done

```
<div id="teams" class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="nav flex-column col-md-1 teamTab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#category1-tab" data-toggle="pill" role="tab">Category1</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#category2-tab" data-toggle="pill" role="tab">Category2</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#category3-tab" data-toggle="pill" role="tab">Category3</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content col-md-11">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="category1-tab" style="padding-left: 60px; padding-right:100px">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Name</h5>
                    <p class="card-title">position</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="category2-tab">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Category 2 Name</h5>
                    <p class="card-title">position</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="category3-tab">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Category 3 Name</h5>
                    <p class="card-title">position</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

currently, the content for all tabs is shown at the same place. However, i wanted the content to be shown just beside(with a little bit in bottom position) its respective tab.

--Category 1

```
           name position
```

Category 2

```
          category 2 name position if clicked this one show in this 
          position
```

Category3

```
          similarly if clicked here should be shown its related content 
          here not on the top
```

Comment: Check this out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/
It can help you.

Comment: i have done from there but my question is how can i show content just beside respective tab not the content of all tabs at same top position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution:
Add `.child` class to all your content DIVs having class `.tab-pane` and remove inline styles.

```
.child {
  padding-left: 60px; 
  padding-right:100px
}
```

Then use this JS code to show Tab content below the Tab title.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.nav-link').each(function(){
      var content_id = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).after($(content_id).hide());
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(content_id).show();
      }
   });

    $('.nav-link').on('click', function(){
        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.tab-pane').hide();
        $(content_id).show();
    });
});
```

Hope it will work for you. OR check working [code here](https://codepen.io/sssurii/pen/BaaYvJa)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Can't we show content of category 1 initially?

Comment: @Serenity I have update JS code to show active tab content by default. Just added check If the tab has active class show the content for it. hope it is fine now.

Comment: yup it is as expected. Thank you very much.